Does vinyl sash framing keep double-glazed window units together?
Long detailed explanation about why I have this situation after the asking of the initial question.
I'm utilizing some upcycled vinyl-framed double-glazed windows in the construction of a shed. I am located in a rural area which does not have building inspections or compliance concerns, so this is simply a question of practicality.
The vinyl frames in which the sashes would typically be installed are in very poor condition. I've removed the individual (18"x24") sashes from the vinyl frames and am planning to discard them.
The windows themselves have H-shaped vinyl channels around the two panes of glass, which have begun to deteriorate. Removing these vinyl channels requires about 16 3/4" screws to come out, and then you have a double-glazed windows leftover. (Glass, rubber/silicone weatherseal, metal partition, glass, and that's all.) Since I have some foggy windows, I chose to experiment on one of those before committing to disassembling a good, fogless window.
It would appear that the vinyl U-channel provides a nominal amount of compression to hold the assembly together.
My question is: if I remove the vinyl U-channel and mount the window as a fixed unit in the building, will it be more liable to delaminate over time vs. if it was in its vinyl setting?
Backstory on why I'm even doing this to begin with:
Bought a rural property that was owned by someone who falls between a hoarder and an optimistic construction enthusiast. Loads of building supplies around, including some used (previously installed in a home) builder-grade windows that look like the standard issue double-glaze my grandma was sold in Florida in 2007.
Unclear what the condition of the windows was when they were acquired, but sitting in the woods horizontally through harsh winters for 3+ years (we purchased the property 2 years ago, work stopped 3 years ago) has left more than half the windows foggy, the frames rotting, and the assemblies rusted and frozen.
I need to build a (heated) shed for keeping a small pressure tank warm through the winter, and thought any light coming in would beat a 10'x16' darkroom.
This is not my first construction project, so I've got a plan for how to mount and weather-seal the windows, but I don't anticipate providing extra compression support during that installation.
Appreciate any thoughts to make sure I've approached the idea from as many angles as possible.

Almost any two-pane glass unit is manufactured as a standalone item at a different plant than where the window is built. The vinyl, wood, or other material composing the sash structure is not a required support component. It's mostly a means of suspending the glass unit in the window frame.
So no, I wouldn't have any concerns about using the glass units in a custom frame except that seals in such units fail over time, and if these are already quite old you probably don't have a ton of remaining life before they start to allow ingress of moisture. After that, mildew follows.
